# how to multiply a gekko array of FV or variables to a gekko intermediate array if both have different dimensions without changing the amount of FV?

Tags: arrays, multiplication, gekko

of course there is code afterwards but to keep it simple and to express my problem I will only share this. everything is working fine I basically just need the array "x" to change from size 24 to the number of my other array (in this case 100). The array  can't be changed in the beginning because it is an hour factor so I just want to optimize 24 values and not create a new array and optimize 100 different values. The 24 values need to repeat eachother because the array of size 100 or basically 4 days and 4 hours (4*24+4=100). Of course I will be happy too if someone just know a way without changing dimension but I think this is not possible.

```py
f=[1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06]
x4= [0.045930370209, 0.043303258083, 0.039624317151, 0.039318197146, 0.037919352547, 0.037661007306, 0.034399522806, 0.034002995811, 0.033886332129, 0.037339258323, 0.037931042705, 0.038383778229, 0.038823242557, 0.040123255664, 0.040823891738, 0.04379281023, 0.043943821635, 0.045684085291, 0.046003064191, 0.046954569286, 0.048654216051, 0.049955602478, 0.048859969614, 0.046682038822]
T_g=[10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 12.065722222, 12.065722222, 12.065722222, 12.065722222, 12.065722222, 12.065722222, 12.065722222, 12.065722222, 12.065722222, 12.065722222, 12.065722222, 12.065722222]
x = m.Array(m.FV,24)
for i in range(24):
            x[i].value = x4[i]
            x[i].lower = 0.01
            x[i].upper = 0.15
            x[i].STATUS=1
e= m.Var(2.7,lb=1,ub=4)
l = m.Var(-35.1,lb=-38,ub=-30)
g = m.Var(7.1,lb=5,ub=9)
h = m.Var(0.142,lb=0.0,ub=1.5)
xop=[None]*1
ysimm=[None]*1
a=[None]*1
index = np.ones(N,int)
for i in range(N):
            index[i]= int(i%24)

a[0]=m.Intermediate((e / (1 + (l / (T_g - 40)) ** g) + h))
ysimm[0]=m.Intermediate(a[0]*f)
xop[0]=m.Intermediate(x[index]*ysimm[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehensions to convert `a` and `ysimm` to lists.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
f=[1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, \
   1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, \
   1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, \
   1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, \
   0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, \
   0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, \
   0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, \
   0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, \
   0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, \
   1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06, 1.06]
x4= [0.045930370209, 0.043303258083, 0.039624317151, 0.039318197146, \
     0.037919352547, 0.037661007306, 0.034399522806, 0.034002995811, \
     0.033886332129, 0.037339258323, 0.037931042705, 0.038383778229, \
     0.038823242557, 0.040123255664, 0.040823891738, 0.04379281023, \
     0.043943821635, 0.045684085291, 0.046003064191, 0.046954569286, \
     0.048654216051, 0.049955602478, 0.048859969614, 0.046682038822]
T_g=[10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, \
     10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, \
     10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.22025, 10.424666667, \
     10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, \
     10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, \
     10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, \
     10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, \
     10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, \
     10.424666667, 10.424666667, 10.424666667, 9.1760277778, \
     9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, \
     9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, \
     9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, \
     9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, \
     9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, \
     9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 9.1760277778, 10.101444444, \
     10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, \
     10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, \
     10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, \
     10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, \
     10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, 10.101444444, \
     10.101444444, 10.101444444, 12.065722222, 12.065722222, \
     12.065722222, 12.065722222, 12.065722222, 12.065722222, \
     12.065722222, 12.065722222, 12.065722222, 12.065722222, \
     12.065722222, 12.065722222]
N = 24
x = m.Array(m.FV,N)
for i in range(N):
   x[i].value = x4[i]
   x[i].lower = 0.01
   x[i].upper = 0.15
   x[i].STATUS=1
e = m.Var(2.7,lb=1,ub=4)
l = m.Var(-35.1,lb=-38,ub=-30)
g = m.Var(7.1,lb=5,ub=9)
h = m.Var(0.142,lb=0.0,ub=1.5)
M = len(f)
index = np.ones(M,int)
for i in range(M):
    index[i]= int(i%24)
a=[(e / (1 + (l / (T_g[i] - 40)) ** g) + h) for i in range(len(T_g))]
ysimm=[a[i]*f[i] for i in range(M)]
xop=[x[index[i]]*ysimm[i] for i in range(M)]
m.solve()
```

Comment: I don't get an answer for this... value is 0. I also want to keep the intermediate because my code uses all intermediates so i get problems if i multiply with a list.

Comment: It's no problem to include the `Intermediate()` in the list comprehension. `ysimm=m.Intermediate([a[i]*f[i]) for i in range(M)]`

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable, I get this error. I have posted new problem where you can see my whole problem is. maybe you will find it easier to solve it then. here is the link to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73423465/how-to-multiply-a-gekko-array-of-fv-or-variables-with-a-gekko-intermediate-array

Comment: I put the bracket in the wrong location. it should be `ysimm=[m.Intermediate(a[i]*f[i]) for i in range(M)]`

Comment: yes I knew this way already but then I'm creating a lot of new intermediates and this is a problem for longer datasetsas explained in my new problem.